# List of SSML tags and features supported with Google Actions

Tags: ssml

I'm trying to write a function that will generate a script read with SSML tags, and with elements of the script being inserted dynamically based on data pulled from the Twitter API.

I can't find a list of SSML tags and features that Actions on Google support. Is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

The basic tags are listed here: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml
But there are actually a lot more tags for example:

```
    <voice gender="male" variant="1"> </voice>
```

You can look at https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S3.2.1 what else is there.